# Use administration views module with commerce kickstart

Tags: commerce

I need to bulk update a custom field in my product display.

Usually I would use the administration views module to achieve this. However, Commerce Kickstart does not seem to allow the 'operations' to display. I guess this is somehow being overridden by the backoffice functionality of Commerce Kickstart.

Any ideas how to get Admin Views working with Kickstart?

Comment: I think they use the Entity API to generate their admin lists, not a view.

Comment: they seem to be views from what I can see

Comment: Figured it out. There is a bulk operations value shown as a field in the view. From there you can choose which bulk operations are to be enabled.